# how to insert a default date type while assigning values in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
insert all
into employee_leave (emp_id ,leave_id,leave_date_from,leave_date_to,loss_of_pay_days)
values('EA12345',1, to_date('07-JUL-2012', 'DD-Mon-YY'), to_date('09-JUL-2012','DD-Mon-YY'),0)
select * from dual;
```

I want to insert date in To_Date('07-JUL-2012', 'DD-Mon-YY') format while 
I tried to insert but its showing error. How to rectify this?

Comment: What is the full error message that you're getting? N.B. You're specifying your year with four digits (which is an excellent thing), but your format mask has a two digit year. It should be 'YYYY' not 'YY'.

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the INSERT ALL or DUAL to insert a single row; you can simply use:

```
INSERT INTO employee_leave(
                           emp_id,
                           leave_id,
                           leave_date_from,
                           leave_date_to,
                           loss_of_pay_days
                          )
VALUES (
        'EA12345',
        1,
        TO_DATE('07-JUL-2012', 'DD-Mon-YYYY'),
        TO_DATE('09-JUL-2012', 'DD-Mon-YYYY'),
        0
       );
```

I edited the format mask to fit the date strings; also notice that this relies on the NLS language, while it would be safer to use the ANSI standard for dates:

```
INSERT INTO employee_leave(
                           emp_id,
                           leave_id,
                           leave_date_from,
                           leave_date_to,
                           loss_of_pay_days
                          )
VALUES (
        'EA12345',
        1,
        date '2012-07-07',
        date '2012-07-09',
        0
       );
```

Comment: insert into employee_leave (emp_id ,leave_id,leave_date_from,leave_date_to,loss_of_pay_days)values('EA12345',1,to_date('07-JUL-2012', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),to_date('09-JUL-2012','DD-MON-YYYY'),0)

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: '07-JUL-2012', 'DD-MON-YYYY' FRIEND I NEED TO GET LIKE THIS WHILE INSERT VALUES IN THE TABLE

Comment: It's no clear to me. Do you need to insert a single row in a table, right? If not, please edit the question to clarify your need

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS, which is considered to be shouting and is thus rude. Thanks.

Comment: @janardhanrb `date '2012-07-07'` is a date literal. It is shorthand for `to_date('2012-07-07', 'yyyy-mm-dd')`. Aleksej's insert will do what you want. As for being able to only insert a single row at a time, that's because you're using the `insert into ... values ...` syntax. If you have multiple rows from another table to insert, then you should use the `insert into ... select ...` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your nls formating is not english.

I mean try  this to understand month name:

```
  select to_char(to_date('20160701','yyyymmdd') ,'Mon') from dual
```

If the result is   'Jul' it is ok but if it is 'Tem' (in turkish) you cant insert that date because it gives this error:

**ORA-01843: not a valid month**

Comment: FRIEND I NEED TO INSERT DATE IN THE TABLE LIKE THIS ('07-JUL-2012', 'DD-MON-YYYY')

Answer (score 0):

In your dates you have supplied a 4-digit year, but your date pattern specifies a 2-digit year. Change your insert statement to

```
insert all
  into employee_leave
    (emp_id,        leave_id,              leave_date_from,
     leave_date_to,                        loss_of_pay_days)
  values
    ('EA12345',     1,                     to_date('07-JUL-2012', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 
     to_date('09-JUL-2012','DD-MON-YYYY'), 0)
  select * from dual
```

Best of luck.

Comment: FRIEND THANKS IT'S WORKING BUT WHY I AM NOT ABLE TO INSERT MORE THAN ONE ROW AT A TIME

Comment: output:EMP_ID

LEAVE_ID

LEAVE_DATE_FROM

LEAVE_DATE_TO

LOSS_OF_PAY_DAYS

EA12345 1 07/07/2012 07/09/2012 0 
EA12567 1 01/18/2012 02/10/2012 5 
sap12570 3 08/08/2012 08/12/2012 0

Comment: As said, CAPS are considered shouting, so please avoid them. Also, how can your latest comment be useful to understand what you need? Again, please edit your question to clarify your need; do you need to insert a single row? many rows, all equals each other? many different rows? ....

Comment: BUT I EXPECTED RESULT IS  LIKE THIS
EMP_ID

LEAVE_ID

LEAVE_DATE_FROM

LEAVE_DATE_TO

LOSS_OF_PAY_DAYS

EA12345 1 07/07/2012 09/07/2012 0                                                       EA12567 1 18/01/2012 10/02/2012 5

Comment: Please turn your Caps Lock off. And the question about how to use Oracle's `INSERT ALL` to insert more than one row is a different question, and should be posted as a separate question. Thanks.